# Classic ASP wildcard for matching URLs, two ways I've seen, what are the differences?

Tags: asp, web.config

Are these equally valid but with different syntax or is one "correct" and the other not?

`<match url="^.*" ignoreCase="false" />`
vs

`<match url="*" />`

What if any difference does the "^" add vs. just "*"?

And as a bonus question, why would case sensitivity matter?  "Google.com" just doesn't exist, right?  Domains are always lower case AFIK.

Answer (score 1):

[Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)

`^` (anchor) the match must start at the beginning of the string
`.` (character class) wildcard: matches any single character except `\n`
`*` (quantifier) matches the previous element zero or more times

`"^.*"` means all the characters from the beginning

`"*"` I would expect a quantifier by itself to be invalid

> why would case sensitivity matter?

The domain name is not case sensitive but directories and files are.

Answer (score 0):

Well shame on me, it's like this:

"Specifies one of any character not in the set, as in  `st[^oa]ck`, which excludes "stock" and "stack" but returns "stick" and "stuck." The caret (^) must be the first character after the left bracket ([) that introduces a set."

Which, OK, but not sure why bother when you can exclude whatever you want with plain old "*" and just filter what you want with a Case/End Case.

If anyone wants to jump in and clarify why "^*" is better, appreciated.

Comment: That isn't the meaning of `^` in this context (outside square brackets).  See [Anchors: string start ^ and end $](https://javascript.info/regexp-anchors)